# App Store Review Approval - Two Factor Authentication

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

For security and privacy reasons of our app, we enforce two factor authentication. After the user logs in for the first time, we ask them set up two factor authentication. App shows them a QR code which can be scanned on any free/paid Authenticator App (e.g. Google Authenticator).

Do you think this should cause trouble for getting app reviewed/approved in App Store Review process.

Comment: huh? how is the user suppose to scan the code with his phone if the code is shown on his phone?

Comment: Majority of the users will be using the app on an iPad. For the users using it on the phone, they will have ability manually enter the security key in the authenticator app, rather than scanning the QR code. Thanks

Comment: This shouldn't cause any problem.  It might take review a little longer than usual, but this case is why you can add review notes.  Just provide the review team with the steps they need to follow to log in and credentials for a test account.

Comment: Thanks, I submitted the app couple days ago, I have made the video on how to setup and use two factor authentication and added the link in the review notes. Lets see how long its takes. I'll keep you posted

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: Have it got approved? If yes then how much time did it took?

Answer (score 0):

Replying a little bit late as the solution we actively use doesn't appear to be listed.

We have had similar issues with this topic (although our Multi-Factor Authentication System was SMS based).

As we didn't want to bypass our production security mechanisms or re-develop a demonstration mode, we have used a platform allowing to assign temporary virtual phone numbers to users in our apps. The platform is called [GetMyMFA.io](https://get.mymfa.io) and it allows us to review and approve our app within 24 hours.

To use it we simply created a user in our production application with a virtual phone number attached which we can enable and disable in real time for the App Store review process. That way Apple simply needs to log in to the platform (with a specific and private username/password) and the SMS MFA login code is displayed in the website.

The objectives of building this platform have been:

1. Avoid spending time in a security "bypass" (and all the security issues that often come with it)
2. Avoid building a "demonstration" mode exclusively for Apple
3. Avoid using public websites with public phone numbers accessible to anyone.

Our App gets approved within 24h with this system and the user can be easily and safely disabled.

Comment: We're experiencing something similar and getting the following back from Apple. Guideline 4.2.3 - Design - Minimum Functionality. "We were required to install authenticator app before we could use your app. Apps should be able to run on launch, without requiring additional apps to be installed."

Next Steps: "To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure that users can use it upon launch. If your app requires authentication before use, please use methods that can authenticate users from within your app".

Comment: I see, this is the main reason why I believe that SMS-based MFA will remain the "go-to" solution for regulated businesses. Explicitly requiring a Time-based OTP might be too much of a burden for non-technical users...